# MongoDB atlas connection SSL error

Tags: mongodb

In all mongoDB examples I can find, those all connect to localhost.  I want to connect to an cloud mongoDB atlas. Here is the code

```
Needs["MongoLink`"]

MongoConnect["mongodb://myusername:mypassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-XXXXXX.\mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxxx.mongodb.net:27017,\
cluster0-shard-00-02-xxxx.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=\
Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"]


MongoGetDatabaseNames[mongoClient]
```

Keep getting the error:

[image]

This relates to a SSL error.  There is command $MongoDefaultCAFile, that gives me a certificate.  Don't know how to use it.  A specific step here will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might need to provide more details. For instance, could you include the exact code that caused that error (paste it as text!)?

Comment: @MarcoB   Please see the code above, I masked specific server name.

Comment: @user1470393 Just letting you know that the server name is also in the image you posted.

Comment: @CarlLange thanks

Comment: @user1470393 You may consider asking WRI support for help here. Sadly I've never used `MongoLink`, so I'm unable to help you.